Why free storage space dip on MySQL replica?
I have AWS RDS MySQL 8.0.36 primary-replica setup. I see this storage free space dip on the replica only. Any ideas why it happened?


No idea why it happened, only a guess: someone executed a query on one replica that created a large temp table on disk. That could explain why it only happened on one replica instance, and why it was so brief.

The only thing that could create a significant dip in diskspace is logging
What kind of logging ???

Error Log : AWS will spew out warning messages about mysql_native_password being old and suggesting using new caching_sha2_password plugin. You should be seeing this on all MySQL 8.x RDS Instances.
Relay Log : While replicas do no have binary logs enabled, relay logs must be enabled for RDS replicas. While mysql has a cap on the maximum size of a binary log and relay_log, a transaction (no matter how large) is saved in one binlog (or relay log) and never split between binlogs. Once the limit is reached, mysqld will delete the relay log and open a new one.
Slow Query Log : If the slow query log is enabled, it will grow. AWS is supposed to be rotating it on a daily basis.
Generag Log : If the general log is enabled, it will grow.

Thre are other logging setups but are not recoverable (such as increased size in ibdata1 due to a large transaction).
You may want to submit an AWS ticket to answer this one since the dip is free space is about 600GB in a short span of time.
Questions

Did you do any autoscaling of the RDS PRIMARY on 2024-07-26 ?
Any large transactions from the PRIMARY replicating to the replica ?
Do the PRIMARY and REPLICA share the same DB Parameter Group ?
Did enable slow query logging or the general log for ther PRIMARY ?


Thank you, Rolando.
No, I didn't see autoscaling event or heavy transactions.
In fact, this free storage dip was on only one replica from three.
I suspect only AWS knows the real answer...
